# navigator.camera.getPicture not calling success call?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, camera

camera.getPicture for capturing the image in the cordova. The project was developed using cordova 3.2.0. Now I have updated Cordova to 3.8.0. Now the navigator.camera.getPicture is not calling both success call and fail call. After doing some trial i have found out that its happening due to adding of these 3 parameter in to the      options

```
allowEdit : true,
targetWidth: 250,
targetHeight: 250,

var options = {
    quality         : 100,
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType      : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType    : Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    allowEdit : true,
    targetWidth: 250,
    targetHeight: 250,
    correctOrientation: 0,
    //popoverOptions  : popover
};
```

When i removes those parameter it is working fine. Could any one guide me what is happening here? Thanks you for your help.

Comment: what error message you got?

Comment: no error message even the fail method was not called. Got it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it worked. The problem was i have updated the cordova. But the camera plugin was still old. So i need to un istall the old camera plugin and re install it.